# How to override a disqus comment count with the comment count from my Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, disqus

My first question here! I want to override the disqus "1 Comentario y 0 Reacciones" from the left part of the theme to just the comment count. It shoud look like the [image attached](http://i728.photobucket.com/albums/ww290/itos/Workeet/workeet-disqus-comments.jpg).

I have searched the database for a similar problem but no luck.

Here is [my blog in the test server](http://s4401.at2.pressdns.com/) if you want to check out.

I have tried to put this code in the functions.php of my theme so the Disqus doesn't override the comments from the theme.

```
// Disqus: Prevent from replacing comment count
remove_filter('comments_number', 'dsq_comments_text');
remove_filter('get_comments_number', 'dsq_comments_number');
remove_action('loop_end', 'dsq_loop_end');
```

Also the output Javascript option in the Advanced options of the Disqus plugin, But no luck with that. Hope someone help me (I will owe you a beer!)

**Update**: Apparently the problem happens in the home, category, search pages but not in the single post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after looking @dInGd0nG post [link](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-prevent-disqus-from-overriding-your-wordpress-comment-count/) I found the **simple solution** to this  problem. Just go to functions.php of your wordpress theme and insert this snippet:

```
// Disqus: Prevent from replacing comment count
remove_filter('comments_number', 'dsq_comments_text');
remove_filter('get_comments_number', 'dsq_comments_number');
remove_action('loop_end', 'dsq_loop_end');
```

That's all. And it's better than going to the Advanced tab from the Disqus plugin and outputting the Javascript in the footer, since that would make it slower.

Comment: Maybe this was working for the old Disqus, since Disqus has upgraded it's service to the new Disqus 2012, this could not work the same.